# Method to show that an operator maps non-negative functions to non-negative functions

Tags: stochastic-processes, operator-theory, semigroups

I am confused about a proof.

Let $E$ be a locally compact and separable metric space, denote $C_0(E)$ the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity, and $E^\Delta$ the one-point compactification of $E$.  We let $T(t)$ be a strongly continuous contraction (i.e., $||T(t)|| \le 1$) semi-group on $E$ which is positive (i.e., maps non-negative functions into non-negative functions).  We define the operator $T^\Delta(t)f = f(\Delta) + T(t)(f - f(\Delta))$ and wish to show that it is also positive.

The purported proof claims that "we must show that if $\alpha \in R, f \in C_0(E), \alpha + f \ge 0$ then $\alpha + T(t)f \ge 0$".  I don't see why this would constitute proof that $T^\Delta$ is positive, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand,  $T^\Delta$ is supposed to be an extension of $T$ to $C(E^\Delta)$, correct?

Since
$$
  C(E^\Delta)= \mathbb R\cdot 1 \oplus C_0(E),
  $$
any such extension is determined by the value of $T^\Delta(t)$  at $1$,
and the given formula seems to indicate a desire to set $T^\Delta(t)(1)=1$.

This said,  an equivalent  way to define $T^\Delta(t)$ is by setting
$$
  T^\Delta(t)(\alpha 1+f) =   \alpha 1+T(t)(f),\quad \forall \alpha\in \mathbb R,\quad \forall f\in C_0(E).
  $$
Seeing things from this angle positivity of $T^\Delta(t)$ is clearly expressed by the given condition.

Comment: Yes we want to extend the operator to $C(E^\Delta)$.  I think my background knowledge here is lacking as I am still confused by your answer.  What does $R \cdot 1 \oplus C_0(E)$ mean?  And why is such an extension determined by the value at $1$?

Comment: By "$1$" I mean the constant function 1 on $E^\Delta$.  By "$\mathbb R\cdot 1$" I mean the linear subspace of $C(E^\Delta)$ spanned by
1, a.k.a. the set of constant functions.  Next we need to identify $C_0(E)$ with the subspace of $C(E^\Delta)$ formed by the functions
$f$ such that $f(\Delta)=0$.  Thus $\mathbb R\cdot 1$ and $C_0(E)$ are linear subspaces of $C(E^\Delta)$ whose
intersection os $\{0\}$ and whose sum  coincides with $C(E^\Delta)$.  All of this implies that    $C(E^\Delta)$ is the direct sum of
$\mathbb R\cdot 1$ and  $C_0(E)$.  Is this much OK?